# Is there any way to cancel a webkit that already has a value of none?

Tags: html, css, webkit, styling

How would you cancel the webkit/moz/etc. value of none on something were the default isn't none? Here is an example:

## CSS

```
.container {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}

.inside {
}
```

## HTML

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="inside">
    </div>
</div>
```

What would you put in .container to negate the -webkit-user-select: none;? This is needed if you want everything inside formatted by the -webkit-whatever attribute except for a few certain things.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question. If you want to remove default property of the browser - you can just override it by your css.

```
{
  (-prefix-)user-select: none;
  OR
  (-prefix-)user-select: text;
  OR
  (-prefix-)user-select: all;
  OR
  (-prefix-)user-select: element;
}
```

If you want to negate that rule on someone's site - open console and add custom style. For instance

```
-webkit-user-select: all;
```

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear, it's a weird situation. Basically the default for user-select normally isn't none but I'm using it in the container div. I want it to apply to everything in the container div except for a couple things. I'm wondering what CSS I have to put in the certain things within the container to change the user-select back to whatever the default is.

Comment: Then you should use diffirent styles on that 'couple of things'. Wrap them inside span element with custom style. Or any other tag really. Depends on content inside them